# Change DataGrid ScrollBar visibility on mouse over?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, scrollbar, visibility

How can I toggle the visibility of a DataGrid scrollbar on the IsMouseOver property of DataGrid?

I want to make the scrollbar visible when the mouse hovers over the DataGrid and invisible when the mouse goes out of the DataGrid. A XAML example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would apply a new style, something like this:

```
<Style x:Key="dataGridStyle" TargetType={x:Type DataGrid}>
   <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
   <Style.Triggers>
       <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
           <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
       </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```

Comment: By far the best solution, and I personally prefer the XAML solutions over a code behind solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Create a value converter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(ScrollBarVisibility))]
sealed class MouseOverToScrollBarVisibility : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((bool)value) ? ScrollBarVisibility.Auto : ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Declare it somewhere in resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MouseOverToScrollBarVisibility x:Key="MouseOverToScrollBarVisibility" />
</Window.Resources>
```

And use it to bind `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` property to `IsMouseOver` property:

```
<DataGrid ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility=
          "{Binding IsMouseOver,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                    Converter={StaticResource MouseOverToScrollBarVisibility}}">
</DataGrid>
```